# defining Partial class constructor parameters when property is an array

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, generics

I have a class with an array property of a type which extends another type. I want to define the constructor parameters as a Partial of the class which allows the array elements to be also a Partial type.

Example:

```
class Foo {
  foo: string;
  constructor({ foo = "foo" }: Partial<Foo> = {}) {
    this.foo = foo;
  }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
  bar: string;
  constructor({ bar = "bar", ...rest }: Partial<Bar> = {}) {
    super(rest);
    this.bar = bar;
  }
}

class Baz {
  bars: Bar[];
  constructor({ bars = [] }: Partial<Baz> = {}) {
    this.bars = bars.map((bar) => new Bar(bar));
  }
}
```

When I pass an array of foo[] to the constructor, typescript shows an error:

```
const foo = new Foo();
const bar = new Bar(foo);
const baz1 = new Baz({ bars: [foo] }); //Property 'bar' is missing in type 'Foo' but required in type 'Bar'
const baz2 = new Baz({ bars: [bar] });
```

One non-generic way to declare this would be:

```
class Baz {
  bars: Bar[];
  constructor({ bars = [] }: { bars?: Partial<Bar>[] | undefined } = {}) {
    this.bars = bars.map((bar) => new Bar(bar));
  }
}
```

But this is not very generic and does not scale with bigger classes. Is there a more generic way to declare this?

Comment: Why would expect it to work ? You can't do `const bar:Bar = new Foo();`

Comment: Where do I try this? I'm doing `const bar:Bar = new Bar(new Foo);`. And it works with the declaration inside the last code block I posted. But i want a more generic way.

Comment: It's a type issue, not a constructor issue. You can test your code on the playground https://www.typescriptlang.org/play

Comment: I don't understand where you see a type issue and why my code works if there is one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be looking for a `DeepPartial<T>` utility type that recursively sets all properties and subproperties to be [optional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties):

```
type DeepPartial<T> = { [K in keyof T]?: DeepPartial<T[K]> }
```

Then you can define the input to `Baz`'s constructor as `DeepPartial<Baz>` which you can verify is equivalent to

```
type DeepPartialBaz = {
    bars?: ({
        bar?: string;
        foo?: string;
    } | undefined)[];
}
```

and therefore it automatically behaves the way you want:

```
class Baz {
    bars: Bar[];
    constructor({ bars = [] }: DeepPartial<Baz> = {}) {
        this.bars = bars.map((bar) => new Bar(bar));
    }
}

const foo = new Foo(); // okay
const bar = new Bar(foo); // okay
const baz1 = new Baz({ bars: [foo] }); // okay
const baz2 = new Baz({ bars: [bar] }); // okay

declare const dpb: DeepPartialBaz;
const baz3 = new Baz(dpb); // okay
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8BQ0PQGaIFzQgBcAnASwDsBzAbnU2HnKOIFdhD5iAKZbRaALzQARDnjDoAX3wAFMMUKkwIADwJ4APkEpJAShR1MmQgAtSEAHRjtY2kcmoHqUJBgAhedACmAD0JfyABMYdQMjACN5fGYKGkNoBiYSNg5uXkjibWEM4QAaaAtC4i8iKVl5RWUVD2ItIWQ9MKNMCBYABy9uYqJdO2aMU3MLDO0MvowHJ0IATw7oABEvLza5BSVVABU6lGgAbQBpaApoAGsvafgsaA2AXQB+fEXl1crNg5utJ2dwKGgPAC8mhgMhB8DVdjdxglGMwUpweNAQdoIWUFksVhV1tUwP9tg19Gh+gMzJYkUIQRYALZgNpcLgZfQCLTkLwAdz+8np8l0vXik1QAucMMIfCQQhZ7PUXF5iVKI3FbI53DEMuFiJxAEZtBKOf8ESD8LsxDcpKqkur-gAmbWKgH6+SgvYZE16WioGZzeYyNzaQmYEEPaA8eIReSBmJUKFGMThkixKGSaAAH2gLCCXiwFC8gV0ENoDkCXhcxWh5sCbXCj29tFlIsi-wAzDb2Xby+FetAAPSd6DwE5gaaoIA)

Comment: Absolutely perfect! Thanks!